# How do I make case function non case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, case

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function redirect() {
            var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
            switch(input) {
                case 'ALCOA':
                    window.location.replace('alcoa-Forms.htm');
                    break;
                case 'alcoa':
                    window.location.replace('/alcoa-Forms.htm');    
                    break;
```

How do I make it so this function is not case sensitive so I can just write it once?

Comment: I guess no one caught on that the whole benefit is to make the case options readable like camel case yet keep them insensitive. I guess there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

simplest way is to make the input all upper or all lower case.  Take your pick:

```
input = input.toUpperCase();
switch (input) {
   case 'ALCOA':
      ...
```

Keep in mind that this will also work for `Alcoa`, `aLcOa`, etc.

You could also just write `case` twice:

```
switch (input) {
   case 'ALCOA':
   case 'alcoa':
```

Answer (score 3):

make the input uppercase:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function redirect() {
        var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        input = input.toUpperCase()
        switch(input) {
            case 'ALCOA':
                window.location.replace('alcoa-Forms.htm');
                break;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your input to either lower or upper case. For example:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .toLowerCase() or .toLocaleLowerCase()
Note that these functions are nearly identical with some obscure exceptions in languages such as Turkish.

### Code

```
function redirect() {
     var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
     switch (input) {
        case 'alcoa':
            window.location.replace('alcoa-Forms.htm');
            break;
    }
}
```

### More detailed

A function is not "case sensitive".  Rather, *your code* is case sensitive.  The way to avoid this problem is to *normalize* the input to a single case before checking the results.  One way of doing so is to turn the string into all lowercase before checking.

### An alternate solution

Use the case fallthrough syntax:

```
switch(text) { 
     case 'a':
     case 'A':
         doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though `.toLowerCase()` (or `.toUpperCase()`) is the simplest way, there is also a regex way:

```
if (/^alcoa$/i.test(input)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use toUpperCase() then inside switch(input) function 
case string should be all in upper case like below:

```
   var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();
    switch (input) {
       case 'ALCOA':
               // do something
               break;
    }
```

if you use toLowerCase() then inside switch(input) function 
case string should be all in lower case like below:

```
 var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
switch (input) {
   case 'alcoa':
           // do something
           break;
}
```